# cycle through a sequence and return modulo

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a sequence of integers that goes from 1 to 7 : `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` (those are actually array keys)

I need a function that takes an integer as a parameter and would return the next item in that sequence. It would kind of "cycle" through that sequence, or "iterate over" that sequence. Not sure if clear enough so here are some examples :

`myNextNumber(3)` would return `4`, `myNextNumber(7)` would return `1`, `myNextNumber(1)` would return `2`

I would need the same for the previous number : `myPreviousNumber(3)` would return `2`, `myPreviousNumber(7)` would return `6`, `myPreviousNumber(1)` would return `7`,

Those 2 functions are steps of +1 or -1 from the parameter. That would be great if I could merge these 2 functions into just one that could accept a second parameter that would be the step of `+1` or `-1` or anything else, like `+42`, which would "cycle through" the sequence six times before it return the correct index. But that would be too much asking. Right now I would be grateful for a guidance with `myNextNumber()`. I'm pretty sure a very trivial one-liner with a modulo operator is all what it needs but I cannot make it work.

Comment: Well, if the size of the array is N, if you're at index x and you want to move y steps forward, your index would be (x + y) mod N. If you want to go y steps backwards, then (x - y) mod N is your new index. However, the second one might be negative (since in most programming languages negative number modulo is still negative) I'd suggest using (((x - y) mod N) + N) mod N (to transform the negative result into the positive one). The one liner would be then (((x + y) mod N) + N) mod N, no matter if the y is positive or not.

Comment: That's what I started with, however the fact that my associative array index starts at 1 instead of 0 defeats your suggestion. https://3v4l.org/jerEA

Comment: You could always subtract 1 to your index, and add it back before returning, and @Maras suggestion would work.

Comment: @Musa I don't really see the problem, instead of returning array[res] return array[res + 1], thats all. Or just change the formula to: (((x - 1 + y) mod N) + N) mod N) + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code

```
function getKey($current, $step): int
{
    $keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    $currentKey = array_search($current, $keys);
    $size = count($keys);

    // normalize step offset
    $step = ($step % $size) + $size;
    //       ^-----------^  ^-----^
    //              │          └ move possible negative to positive
    //              └ get a value from -7 to +7
    
    // add offset for current key
    $newKey = ($currentKey + $step) % $size;
    //         ^-----------------^  ^-----^
    //                  │              └ wrap around in case we exceed $size
    //                  └ add normalized step offset to new element to current
    return $keys[$newKey];
}

// Tests

echo getKey(1,-1) . PHP_EOL;
echo getKey(3,1) . PHP_EOL;
echo getKey(7,1) . PHP_EOL;
echo getKey(7,15) . PHP_EOL; // same as +1
echo getKey(1,-8) . PHP_EOL; // same as -1
echo getKey(1,-15) . PHP_EOL; // same as -1
```

Output

```
7
4
1
1
7
7
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/T3fUr).

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getNextNumber(int[] array, int index) {
    index = Math.floorMod(index, array.length) + 1;
    return array[index];
}
```

I don't know PHP, but I guess this is accurate:

```
function getNextNumber(&$array, int $index) {
    $index = fmod($index, count(array)) + 1
    return $array[$index]
```

Answer (score 0):

this functions will do the trick, you should use mod to find the number ( for php and java is '%');

```
function myNextNumber($i){
     if($i>6){
       return ($i%7)+i;
     }
     return $i+1;
}


function myPreviousNumber($i){
    if($i>8){
       return $i%7-1;
    }
    if($i == 1){
      return 7;
    }
    return $i-1;
}

function myNextNumber($i, $param){
   if($param == 1){
     return myNextNumber($i);
   }

   if($param == -1){
     return myPreviousNumber($i);
   }
   
   return 'Invalit Param';
}
```